# plotting a single x with multiple y values without individually specifying all y values mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhVaT.png)

I use the table above where column 1 are the `x` values and the subsequent columns are the `y` values to be plotted against the `y` values. This is imported from excel.

I use:

```
tbl = Import["Book2.xlsx"][[1]];
ListPlot[{tbl[[All, {1, 2}]], tbl[[All, {1, 3}]], tbl[[All, {1, 4}]]}]
```

and it plots them in a single plot just how I want it.

However, say I don't have just 3 `y` values, but I have 1000, how would I do the same input as above but without typing them out to 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListPlot[Table[tbl[[All, {1, i}]],{i,2,1000}]]
```